# How to delete folder that is in document directory in android 11 and above

Tags: java, android, kotlin, storage, android-11

I tried below code to delete that folder but its going in catch

My app folder is in : /storage/emulated/0/Documents/AppFolder/AppDB.db

```
File dbfile = new File(folder,  Constant.KEY_DB_FILE_NAME + ".db");
                try {
                    this.deleteFile(dbfile.getPath());

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("test==>", "catch" + e.getMessage());
                }
```

```
catch==> File /storage/emulated/0/Documents/SamparkSetuFolder/SamparkSetuDB.db contains a path separator
```

Comment: `new File(folder...` What is `folder`? Please declare variable in your code. We wanna see what you do.

Comment: `storage/emulated/0/Documents/SamparkSetuFolder/SamparkSetuDB.db` Is that a folder? Looks more a path to a .db file.

Comment: Post your deleteFile() function.

Comment: Ever tried `dbfile.delete()`?

Comment: My folder path:

                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + File.separator + "AppFolder/");

Comment: Post your deleteFile() function.  ( this is default function)
Ever tried dbfile.delete()?  ( yes but its return false not working)

Comment: Try doing the same with MediaStore. Make sure that the file is being owned by you before deleting, if not you have to start an Intent Sender for the same to ask for the permission from the user to delete the file.